# Can I be using a VPN on my computer to connect to a remote desktop and use a VPN on that remote desktop at the same time?

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, tor

I wanted to ask if it is necessary to connect to a remote desktop using a VPN and if it is, can I be using a VPN to connect to that remote desktop and using a VPN on that remote desktop to connect to an onion router. I need some help with this.